# Material/Texture offset from object?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]I imagine someone new like me has ask this question and it's probably buried here somewhere - but i'm having problems with the material/texture offset by itself from the object as a flat plane.  It's weird and probably something very simple to fix lol.  I'm attaching a pic and hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand what is the problem, what do you mean by offset, what are you supposed to see? Also maybe pack your image and share your file?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Addons* , and look for *Node Wrangler* then enable it

In the *Shader Editor* , select the *Image Texture* node , and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,

A *Mapping* node will be added , now adjust the *Location* until you get what you want.